# Edit that only changed a "jsbin" (or similar websites) link

Tags: discussion, review-queues, jsfiddle

I encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8260678) edit, where the only change was a change in the "jsbin" (a website that allows one to upload a JS, HTML and CSS snippet that can be nicely manipulated, similarly to jsfiddle and such) link.

Although the edit might have been a good edit, I rejected it because I believe that it is out of scope for a reviewer to check a 3rd party website.

However, AFAIY, answers that rely on 3rd party websites links, like "jsbin" are generally allowed in SOF.

How should I handle such proposed edits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely reject those edits. Reviewers should not have to visit another site to confirm if an edit is helpful or not (*except in maybe cases of broken/typo-mistake links that needed fixing*).

That answer is actually Not-An-Answer. It's just a link to the supposedly "working solution". The relevant solution code should always be put in the answer itself, not just linked to.

It's fine to include links to jsbin/jsfiddle/etc. But they are not a replacement for posting the code in the answer itself.